# Integrate iPhone scroll on home page

Tags: iphone, scroll, html

sorry for the weird syntax of my problem. I would like to integrate on my home page an iPhone and when you scroll the view inside the iPhone change.
You can understand by checking this website : https://www.happn.com/it/
This is exactly what I would like to integrate on my home page but I have no idea on how to do it myself. Can you help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what framework (if any) do you want to use to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tried anything cause I don't know how to do it myself. I'm open minded to every framework who could help me to do it in an easy way if you know one. Thank you for your answer